# Why doesn't has_one work for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is my expectation that when I create a BrickItem, it will have a reference to a Ability. Yet, when the BrickItem is created, abilities_id is null. Why?

My table create:

```
  create_table "brick_items", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "abilities_id"
```

My Ability migration:

```
  Ability.create :name => 'my choice'
```

My controller:

```
def create
        @brick_item = BrickItem.new(params[:brick_item])
        @brick_item.build_ability(:id => 1)
```

My model:

```
  class BrickItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ability
end
```

Comment: the field should be `choice_id` not `choices_id`

Comment: I have changed the field name to the actual value. Since this is an english language nuance, care to try again?

Comment: does your Ability model belongs_to BrickItem  ??? if it does not, please add belongs_to :BrickItem to your Ability model

Comment: Jorge,my goal is to have a table: Ability with 3 rows. A,B,C. And when I create a new BrickItem, I want it to have a reference to a single Ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the whole picture, but from the code you've shared, it appears there are several problems:

1. You should call the column ability_id, since there's only one
2. If brick item holds the ability_id, then you should use belong_to and not has_one
3. build_ability will only build a new ability. You should use create_ability.

Comment: I don't want to create a new ability everytime I create a new BrickItem, I only want 3 abilities ever.

Comment: So don't use build_ability at all. Change your code to belongs_to and set the id to the ability of your choice.

Comment: To be clearer: Instead of `@brick_item.build_ability(:id => 1)` you can write `@brick_item.ability_id = 1` or @brick_item.ability = some_ability`. In your BrickItem model, change to `belongs_to :ability`

Comment: If this is common to all of the BrickItems then best do it in the model. Else, simply set it to the Ability you want to attach.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't understand your code, if you are trying to create and ability your should look like this (on your ability controller)

```
def create
    @brick_item =  @brick_item = BrickItem.new(params[:brick_item])
    @ability = @brick_item.build_brick_item(params[:ability])
end
```

But I'm not really sure about what are you trying to do.